# Turn button app into a automatic starting app?

Tags: java, android

So i have this app that I want to make automatically gather data( from sensors and listeners )

So currently It has a start button that starts the init and and abort button that stops it.

Now I would like to automate it from the starting when a webpage is done loading , or when user wins a reward in a game etc

Comment: can you share your code?
are you using a webview to show the webpage

Comment: No im not using webview or anything to do that yet im still at app stage

Comment: why dont you call the method which you have written in the button click right after the webpage is done loading or user win event?

Comment: That was my Idea , to use Webview and then onpagefinish() to start it but I cant find any examples of how people have done this when moving from an APP with an GUI because I want to remove all the GUI activity and have it as a backroundserivce of an app that you can just call like a lib

Comment: check these links out
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

http://pastebin.com/42BjZvQ6

can you describe your app and its functionality the flow etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
               {
                  //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
                }
            });
```